# problems with "use of undeclared identifier 'height' " mario.c

Tags: c, cs50

I am really confused about what is going on here. I tried changing the variable and inputting other things, but every single time it would always say, `use of undeclared identifier 'height'`. does anyone know what to do?

here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello!\a");
    
    do
    {
        int height = get_int("pick a number, any number!: ");
    }
    while ( height > 1 || height < 8);
```

p.s. I'm kinda new to this and it's a work in progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`height` is only defined within the loop, due to C's block scoping. This means that it is undeclared in the while condition, causing the compile error. To fix it, move the declaration before the loop:

```c
int height;
do 
{
    height = get_int("pick a number, any number!: ");
}
while ( height > 1 || height < 8);
```

Comment: thank you!!! I was stuck on this for one full hour. everything makes sense now.